# How do I exclude data from local table schema_migrations from being pushed to Heroku DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was able to push my Ruby on Rails app with MySQL(local dev) to the Heroku server along with migrating my model with the command `heroku rake db:migrate`.  I have also read the documentation on [Database Import/Export](http://docs.heroku.com/taps).  Is that doc referring to pushing actual data from my local dev DB to whichever Heroku's DB?  Do I need to modify anything in the file `database.yml` to make it happen?

I ran the following command:

```
heroku db:push
```

and I am getting the error:

```
Sending data
2 tables, 3 records
!!! Caught Server    Exception                                   | ETA:  --:--:--
Taps Server Error: PGError ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
"unique_schema_migrations"
```

I have 2 tables, one I create for my app and the other `schema_migrations`.  The total number of entries among the 2 tables is 3.  I'm also printing the number of entries I have in the table I have created and it's showing 0.

Any ideas what I might be missing or what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I figured out the above, Heroku's DB already have `schema_migrations` the moment I ran migrate.

**New question:** Does anyone know how I can exclude data from a specific table from being pushed to Heroku DB.  The table to exclude in this case will be `schema_migrations`.

**Not so good solution**:
I googled around and someone else was having the same issue. He suggested naming the `schema_migrations` table to `zschema_migrations`.  In this way data from the other tables will be pushed properly until it fails on the last table.  It's a pretty bad solution but will do for the time being.

A better solution will be to use an existing Rails command which can reset a specific table from a database.  I don't think `Rake` can do that.

Comment: Why are you trying to push data to your production app in this way?

Comment: My site is driven by content. Sometimes I want to see how it displays on my local dev server before pushing it live. Pushing data to Heroku is supported as shown by their doc: http://docs.heroku.com/taps

Comment: ugh. just hit the same issue.

Comment: I was able to the push data with fixtures, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options:

1. The [heroku](http://github.com/heroku/heroku/tree/master) gem and the [taps](http://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/tree/master) gem (which it uses to synchronize databases) are both open-source - you could fork them, alter the taps client API to support excluding tables from a push, then alter the heroku gem to use that new option.
2. You could write a wrapper script that uses [pgdump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgdump.html) to backup the schema_migrations table, drops that table, `heroku push`es the database, then reloads the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a guess based on the error you're getting, but `push` looks like it grabs the schema and the data. I'd try push to an empty database.

Comment: That kind of help me figure out what's going on.  When I first ran `db:migrate`, the table `schema_migrations` gets create on the Heroku DB.  When I try to push my local data, it's failing because the value that I have in my local `schema_migrations` is a duplicate of the Heroku. I now need to know how to exclude pushing schema and data from the `schema_migrations` table.

Comment: If you use db:push I think it will create the whole database. This means you don't need to run db:migrate. Push right after creating the database - which in this case I think means right after you create the Heroku application.

Comment: I tried that but it complains that the schemas have not been created yet on the heroku server which is why running migrate seems to be a first step.

Answer (score 0):

I've just deployed a Rails 3 beta app to heroku on their new bamboo server. I can now upload data from my local dev machine to the heroku database by doing:

```
heroku rake db:fixtures:load test/fixtures/my_model.yml
```

The data is then properly propagated in the Heroku database.  Even though I specified a specific data file, it automatically pushes data from my other yaml files. It probably has something to do with my model relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are out of sync you can always reset the Heroku database before pushing using

```
heroku db:reset
```

Answer (score 0):

To push/pull from specific tables

heroku db:pull --tables logs,tags

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/4/21/supporting_big_data_part_1